# How to update multiple tables using one query in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to update three table with one Query in Entity Framework:

```
 Customer_Identification       Region               Customer Account

 | Id                          |Region_Id           |Customer Id
 | Name                        |Region_Name         |Bank_Name
 | Address                                          |Bank Account
 | Region_Id
```

I created a class `Customer` with all fields required and I used a join query to select what information I want to update in database.

I try to update changes in this way :

```
 dataContext.Entry( Customer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
 dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

I get this error:

> The entity type DbQuery`1 is not part of the model for the current context.

How is possible to update database without using multiple queries?

Best regards,

Comment: first thing to keep in mind is to have a single database context to handle all three entities (or tables). second, call `SaveChanges()` once you have done all the necessary changes. this way, your updates will be carried in a single transaction (not necessarily one liner update query).

Comment: You haven't shown your code, but "The entity type DbQuery1" suggests that `Customer` is some intermediate EF type. Not the result of a query, but perhaps the query itself.